# How do I make make my hash table with linear probing more efficient?

Tags: c++, hash, memory-efficient

I'm trying to implement an efficient hash table where collisions are solved using linear probing with step. This function has to be as efficient as possible. No needless `=` or `==` operations. My code is working, but not efficient. This efficiency is evaluated by an internal company system. It needs to be better.

There are two classes representing a key/value pair: `CKey` and `CValue`. These classes each have a standard constructor, copy constructor, and overridden operators `=` and `==`. Both of them contain a `getValue()` method returning value of internal private variable. There is also the method `getHashLPS()` inside `CKey`, which return hashed position in hash table.

```
int getHashLPS(int tableSize,int step, int collision) const
{
    return ((value + (i*step)) % tableSize);
}
```

Hash table.

```
class CTable
{
    struct CItem {
            CKey key;
            CValue value;
        };
    CItem **table;
    int valueCounter;       
}
```

Methods

```
// return collisions count
int insert(const CKey& key, const CValue& val)
{
    int position, collision = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        position = key.getHashLPS(tableSize, step, collision); // get position
        if(table[position] == NULL) // free space
        {
            table[position] = new CItem; // save item
            table[position]->key = CKey(key);
            table[position]->value = CValue(val);
            valueCounter++;
            break;
        }

        if(table[position]->key == key) // same keys => overwrite value
        {
            table[position]->value = val;
            break;
        }

        collision++; // current positions is full, try another

        if(collision >= tableSize) // full table
            return -1;
    }

    return collision;
}

// return collisions count
int remove(const CKey& key)
{
    int position, collision = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        position = key.getHashLPS(tableSize, step, collision);
        if(table[position] == NULL) // free position - key isn't in table or is unreachable bacause of wrong rehashing
            return -1;

        if(table[position]->key == key) // found
        {
            table[position] = NULL; // remove it
            valueCounter--;

            int newPosition, collisionRehash = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++, collisionRehash = 0) // rehash table
            {
                if(table[i] != NULL) // if there is a item, rehash it
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        newPosition = table[i]->key.getHashLPS(tableSize, step, collisionRehash++);
                        if(newPosition == i) // same position like before
                            break;

                        if(table[newPosition] == NULL) // new position and there is a free space
                        {
                            table[newPosition] = table[i]; // copy from old, insert to new
                            table[i] = NULL; // remove from old
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        collision++; // there is some item on newPosition, let's count another

        if(collision >= valueCounter) // item isn't in table
            return -1;
    }

    return collision;
}
```

Both functions return collisions count (for my own purpose) and they return `-1` when the searched `CKey` isn't in the table or the table is full.

Tombstones are forbidden. Rehashing after removing is a must.

Comment: "Efficient hash table with linear probing" is a bit like "efficient bubblesort". You're demanding efficiency from the poster girl for inefficient algorithms. If you care about efficiency, switch to something else.

Comment: I know it, but it is a task, so I have to do it. It is easy to take efficient algorithm, but not that easy implement inefficient algorithm well.

Comment: A chain pointer cost only a pointer or int per node; a free list only on per table. As others have said, with frequent deletions and insertions linear probing might not be the best choice. @Andrew: Homework?

Comment: @wildplasser Sort of. The point isn't choose best solution, but instead use this and solve it as best as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest change for improvement I see is in the removal function. You shouldn't need to rehash the entire table. You only need to rehash starting from the removal point until you reach an empty bucket. Also, when re-hashing, remove and store all of the items that need to be re-hashed before doing the re-hashing so that they don't get in the way when placing them back in.

Another thing. With all hashes, the quickest way to increase efficiency to to decrease the loadFactor (the ratio of elements to backing-array size). This reduces the number of collisions, which means less iterating looking for an open spot, and less rehashing on removal. In the limit, as the loadFactor approaches 0, collision probability approaches 0, and it becomes more and more like an array. Though of course memory use goes up.

***Update***
You only need to rehash starting from the removal point and moving forward by your step size until you reach a null. The reason for this is that those are the only objects that could possibly change their location due to the removal. All other objects would wind up hasing to the exact same place, since they don't belong to the same "collision run".

Comment: Can you tell me, why rehashing from removed position is enough instead of rehashing all the "buckets"?

Comment: @Andrew I've edited the response. Basically, you only need to rehash anything that could possibly fall back to fill in the hole that was made by the removal. Everything else will end up back where it was.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now, thank you. I'll wait for more answers and if no more comes, I'll accept yours ;) It really is very good improvement.

Answer (score 0):

A possible improvement would be to pre-allocate an array of CItems, that would avoid the malloc()s / news and free() deletes; and you would need the array to be changed to "CItem *table;"

But again: what you want is basically a *smooth ride in a car with square wheels*.

Comment: Hm, interesting idea, but not quite completed though. If I pre-allocate array, which should be really large and then system tests it inserting only one item and measure memory taken, it wouln't be good. Perhaps I forgot to mention that all input values choose testing system. But thank you anyway, I can try if it don't watch for memory used.

Comment: The "table[position] = new CItem;" uses exactly the same amount of memory (+more: for the pointer, and the malloc overhead) for the same number of items (and a full table). Plus: it *fragments* memory, which is not what you want.